# How to correctly implement EmbeddedResource _ViewImports & _ViewStart in plugins

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'd like to create embedded _ViewImports file that sets usings, inheritance (to change localization source) for views specific to the plugin. Problem is when I include embedded views like this

```
Configuration.EmbeddedResources.Sources.Add(
    new EmbeddedResourceSet(
        "/Views/",
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
        "MyPlugin.Web.Views"
    )
);
```

Then _ViewImports.cshtml from this plugin's View folder overrides all others for the entire site. What do I need to do to scope it only to views found in the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net core has already a feature [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas)

You need to use Area to make it scoped!

Comment: Indeed, I already resolved it by separating all modules into different areas.